# How to identify a number that has a correspondent negative in a list?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I am beginner in this journey of Python/VBA so I have a problem I kindly want do ask you.

So I have a list of rows in an excel spreadsheet (also I treat this data with Pandas to reduce the number of rows I have to analyse on Excel)

The fact is that I have dozens of thousands rows that in a specific column has values like these:

```
      col
0 -142.60
1  142.60
2 -565.78
3  565.78
4  -90.00
5   90.00
6   63.26
7  -63.26
8  117.96
```

So I just want to know how can I automatically delete rows that has a correspondent negative number and sum = 0.

I only want 117,96 row here.

Comment: Is 117,96 a single number in this context or is it a pair of numbers?

Comment: @Ben it is the only number that is not present as + as well as - value?

Comment: Are your numbers always paired up like this? or may the negative value of a number be farther down or after the positive one?  For you example you could simply use the sum() over the colum to get the (single) value - that wont work if you got multiple unique numbers. What if you got (-10,10,-10) - report -10?

Comment: @PatrickArtner You seem to have not understood my question. The comma in `117,96` can either be interpreted as a decimal point or a separator of a pair of numbers. You seem to have used the second interpretation, whereas mozway used the first.

Comment: @Suno It would be helpful if you could verify for us what exactly the `,` is supposed to mean in `117,96`.

Comment: `8  117.96` ..   some natural languages use `,` as decimal seperator - my guess would be that Suno speaks one of them ;)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Again, the last line being `8  117.96` is a consequence of mozway's edit. In the original, everything was presented with the ambiguous comma delimiter. I think it is likely that mozway's interpretation is correct, but this is really the kind of thing that should be verified.

Comment: @Ben now I got you, sorry, bit dense here. Yeah, OP should clarify that - but doubt will - new contrib, no attempt made etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have float in this column, you can compare the rows with the opposite of the next one, and use this information to subset only those rows.

```
# is the next row the opposite value?
m = df['col'].eq(-df['col'].shift())

# drop the matching rows and the next ones
df2 = df.loc[~(m|m.shift(-1))]
```

output:

```
      col
8  117.96
```

Used input:

```
      col
0 -142.60
1  142.60
2 -565.78
3  565.78
4  -90.00
5   90.00
6   63.26
7  -63.26
8  117.96
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you've decided to use `.eq` rather than the `==` operator?

Comment: @BenGrossmann no, you can use both with the same effect, I just like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the context whether the "correspondent negative number" is necessarily adjacent to the actual number. If the negative number might not be next to the positive number but is just somewhere in the array, we could do the following. Here, `df` is the data frame constructed from the Excel data.

```
# builds the same table with an additional column '_merge'.
# '_merge' column will be 'left_only' for rows whose negative
# does not appear and 'both' otherwise

df_all = df.merge(-df, how='left', indicator=True)

# selects rows with 'left_only' label

df = df.loc[df_all['_merge']=='left_only']
```

Input:

```
        0
0  -63.26
1  117.96
2 -565.78
3   63.26
4  142.60
5  565.78
6   90.00
7  -90.00
8 -142.60
```

Output:

```
        0
1  117.96
```